# ¿Cómo activo la cámara frontal en Android 4.1.2 en tableta?

Tags: android, android-jellybean

Hola a todos tengo un problema con la tableta y es que solo tiene una cámara frontal y tal como está mi programa se ve que no puedo llamar a la cámara.

¿Tenéis alguna sugerencia? He probado con móviles y funciona.

He puesto estos permisos en el manifest

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

<!--Permisos para Marshmallow -->

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Este es el código**

```
//Fotos
    private Intent takePictureIntent;
    private String pathFotoTemporal;
    private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

   //Parte de la camara
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        pathFotoTemporal = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }


    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
            takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        try {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(pathFotoTemporal).into(imageView);

                    if(Entrada==true){
                        GuardarFichar();
                    }
                    if(Salida==true){
                        GuardarSalida();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba añadiendo esta línea a tu código antes de llamar al intent de la cámara (antes del método `startActivityForResult`):

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
```

Comment: No funciona, pero aun así gracias por la aportación seguiré intentándolo.

Comment: Voy a intentar reproducir tu problema, si doy con una solución actualizo la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, por que la verdad no entiendo el por que no funciona, cuando en dispositivos mas actuales si.

Comment: @Meirin.f Acabo de probar tu código añadiendo la línea que te he dicho sobre un dispositivo con Android 4.4.4 (KitKat) y funciona correctamente, se abre el intent con la cámara frontal. ¿Qué pasa exactamente cuando intentas abrir el Intent desde la tablet? ¿Aparece algún error en el LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

cambia esto:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

por esto:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega estos permisos en tu manifext.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

Código de ejemplo

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
        int cameraCount = 0;
        Camera cam = null;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                try {
                    cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        return cam;
    }
```

Comment: No ha sido posible conectarme con la cámara de ninguna forma posible,  si alguien encontrara la solución lo agradecería mucho.